# Elixir: Redefine module in test

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I have an ExUnit test that pings an endpoint. That endpoint calls a function that makes an external call via an http client that is determined by the environment [a la Jose Valim's famous post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/).

In the test environment, I'm using a mock module of HTTPoison.

```
defmodule HTTPoisonMock do
  def get(_url), do: raise "You need to define this function for your test"
end
```

In the test itself, I'm trying to redefine this module so that the function returns a canned response.

```
test "/my_endpoint" do
  defmodule HTTPoisonMock do
    def get(_url) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: []}}
    end
  end

  conn = conn(:get, "/my_endpoint")
  ...

  assert conn.status == 200
end
```

However, the redefined module is not used. I get the original error raised when I run the test.

```
** (ArgumentError) You need to define this function for your test
```

I've tried to do this with the [mock library](https://github.com/jjh42/mock) as well, which raises a different error, even if I'm mocking HTTPoison directly.

```
require HTTPoison

test "/my_endpoint" do
  with_mock HTTPoison, [:get, fn(_url) -> {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: []}} end] do
    conn = conn(:get, "/my_endpoint")

    ...

    assert conn.status == 200
  end
end

** (UndefinedFunctionError) function HTTPoison.start/0 is undefined (module HTTPoison is not available)
```

Why isn't my redefined module being used?

Comment: You can't redefine a module like this as far as I know. Can you post the code you used with `mock` (and the error message if it's not exactly identical to this)?

Comment: @Dogbert I've updated the code with the `mock` version. Error is different.

Comment: Could you try also mocking `:start/0`? Something like `with_mock HTTPoison, [get: fn(_url) -> {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: []}} end, start: fn() -> end] do`.

Comment: @Dogbert that worked, thank you. That error message is misleading, then. Why did it say `module HTTPoison is not available`?

Comment: Oh. I didn't even read that part which is why I suggested adding `start/0`!

Answer (score 4):

It seems the problem is already resolved, but I would answer the original question for future visitors.

To redefine the module in the test, one might:

```
test "/my_endpoint" do
  Code.eval_string """
    defmodule HTTPoisonMock do
      def get(_url) do
        {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: []}}
      end
    end
  """

  # do stuff

  after
    purge HTTPoisonMock
  end
end
```

This is heavily used in Elixir core tests, grep the repo for `purge`.